# Xamarin listview Gesturerecognizer get id

Tags: xamarin, listview

Tengo un problema con un formulario de Xamarin. En concreto se como puedo hacer para obtener el id del objeto seleccionado de un List View de tuplas de objetos. Estoy utilizando GestureRecognizer y llamo a un método u otro en funcion del elemento de la tupla en la que me encuentro, pero no puedo obtener el id del objeto o el row en el que me encuentro.

Mi viewlist es el siguiente:

```
    <Grid Padding="10">
        <ListView SeparatorVisibility="None" ItemsSource="{Binding offertsList}" HasUnevenRows="True" SelectionMode="Single" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" RefreshControlColor="Red" x:Name="listView" >
            <!--ItemSelected="OnSelectItem"-->
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell >
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Frame  IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}" BindingContext="{Binding Item1}" Padding="1" BackgroundColor="#31b0d5" HasShadow="True" OutlineColor="#bbb">
                                <Grid  x:Name="GridItem1">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Frame BackgroundColor="White" Padding="5" HasShadow="False">
                                        <Image Source="{Binding PhotoUrl}"  Aspect="AspectFill" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="80"/>
                                    </Frame>
                                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Padding="5,0,5,5" Spacing="1">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding name}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="16" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding price, StringFormat='{0:C2}.'}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="12" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" TextColor="White"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding link}" FontSize="12" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center"  VerticalOptions="Center" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Grid>
                                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Command="{Binding onClickItem2,Source={x:Reference GridItem1}}"/>
                                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Frame>

                            <Frame Grid.Column="2" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}" BindingContext="{Binding Item2}" Padding="1" BackgroundColor="#31b0d5" HasShadow="True" OutlineColor="#bbb">
                                <Grid  x:Name="GridItem2">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Frame BackgroundColor="White" Padding="5" HasShadow="False">
                                        <Image Source="{Binding PhotoUrl}" Aspect="AspectFill" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="80"/>
                                    </Frame>
                                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Padding="5,0,5,5" Spacing="1">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding name}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="16" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" TextColor="White"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding price, StringFormat='{0:C2}.'}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="12" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" TextColor="White"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding link}" FontSize="12" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center"  VerticalOptions="Center" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" x:Name="linkLabel"/>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Grid>
                                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="onClickItem2" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer CommandParameter="{Binding .}"  Command="{Binding onClickItem2,Source={x:Reference GridItem2}}"/>
                                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Frame>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

y cuando hago click sobre alguno de llos elementos de la tupla ejecuto el seguiente metodo:

```
    async void onClickItem1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender != null)
        {
            OffertPair ofertDetail = (OffertPair)sender;

            Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new OffertPage(ofertDetail.Item1, Util.PageMode.DETAIL.ToString(), userName), this);
            await Navigation.PopAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Please select and offert to go detail", "OK");
        }
    }
```

Ahora, cuando el flujo lleva al metodo sender siempre es un template. Yo necesito identificar el objeto que sobre el que estoy haciendo click de alguna forma.

Tengan en cuenta que en cada fila de la lista hay dos objetos offert ya que s una lista de tuplas.

```
public class OffertPair: Tuple<Offert, Offert>
{
    public OffertPair(Offert offert1, Offert offert2)
     : base(offert1, offert2 ?? CreateEmptyModel()) { }

    private static Offert CreateEmptyModel()
    {
        return new Offert { };
    }
}
```

Que se forma del siguiente modo:

List offertList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject>(response.Content);

```
        //Convert from list<offert> to IEnumerable<OffertPair>
        var offertPairList = offertList.Select((v, i) => new { Index = i, Value = v })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 2, x => x.Value)
        .Select(g => new OffertPair(
```

Muchas Gracias

Comment: ¿Alguna idea sobre como resolverlo? Sigo padeciendo el problema y no se que más probar.Gracias de antemano!!